# ORDER BY first mention, then by another column

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table called 'messages':

```
+-----------+--------+
| timestamp | poster |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 | John   |
|         2 | Peter  |
|         3 | Peter  |
|         4 | Chris  |
|         5 | John   |
+-----------+--------+
```

I want a query to first list all posts by the first poster, then all by the second poster, etc. **without using a subquery**. The first poster is determined by the timestamp. Find out who is first and return all their posts, then who is second:

```
+-----------+--------+
| timestamp | poster |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 | John   |
|         5 | John   |
|         2 | Peter  |
|         3 | Peter  |
|         4 | Chris  |
+-----------+--------+
```

**EDIT**
Ok guys, I made the question way too simple. The very basic examples you are giving work because (J)ohn comes before (P)eter. What if Peter was first? You would need to add DESC to the poster clause. Your SQL statements using the simple ORDER BY do not address the issue of ordering by who is first, second, third, etc.

**EDIT AGAIN**
I added "Chris" to the mix to make it more plain as to what I want. John was the first poster; get all his posts. Then Peter because he is second. Then Chris.

Comment: Where is `timestamp` column ?

Comment: You can learn some basics here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @Prix, changed the link XD

Comment: what's wrong with a sub query, i can't think of a way to do it without a subquery

Comment: What you're asking is out of the capabilities of a simple query with no join/subs not to mention we don't know if that is 1 set of message/conversation or if that is considering multiple different set of conversations which would by itself make it into another level of complications.

Comment: What other columns are in this table?

Comment: @Prix: That's what I wanted to know, if it can be done without a subquery or not.

Comment: @Jack: Many other columns. It is a 3 or 4 table INNER JOIN. That's partly why I didn't want to use a subquery to further complicate the SQL statement.

Comment: i can only think of one way without a subquery, that's by using group_concat so the data is represented differently. see my answer below

Comment: @JFriend if you have 4 other tables of/for messages then you have something really wrong with your database.

Comment: @Prix That would be a correct statement. The actual database has nothing to do at all with messages. :) It's orders, order lines, transactions, shipments, etc. all tied together in one data presentation for invoice processing.

Comment: well unless you provide trustful and right information you will not get a right answer nor we will be able to read the crystal ball to help you on that. All you will get is guesses.

Comment: @Prix Correct. That's why I greatly simplified it into a common scenario of a messaging system. I'm not looking for an answer to the data structure, just the harvesting of it. I know precisely what I need for the task. And the original question (with edits) describes that need.

Comment: If the general consensus is that it cannot be done without a subset of results, the someone should write a simple answer clearly explaining why it won't work and give an SQL example with a subquery that will produce the requested results.

Comment: That should be your task not ours we are pointing you to the way not working for you. You're not showing any efforts on your side you are pretty much forcing the job on us and that's not what SO is here for.

Comment: @Prix - I can answer my own question, but how does that help anyone else's reputation? If someone wants to answer so we can move on, then please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no other way than to create another result set and join with that:

```
SELECT poster, MIN(timestamp) AS first_ts
FROM messages
GROUP BY poster
ORDER BY first_ts;
```

Result:

```
+--------+-----------+
| poster | first_ts  |
+--------+-----------+
| John   | 1         |
| Peter  | 2         |
| Chris  | 4         |
+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would join to your query in such a way as to give the desired result set? Or are you referring to making a loop in the application?

Answer (score 1):

can't think of a way to do without a subquery,

but if you can accept your answer as timestamps of csv list. then here is one way.

```
SELECT poster,
       GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp ORDER BY timestamp) as timestamps       
FROM messages
GROUP BY poster
ORDER BY MIN(timestamp)
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5def45/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY poster ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on what @Deepak wrote, you need two fields in the `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT timestamp, poster 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY poster, timestamp;
```

This will give you the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TableName 
 ORDER BY poster ASC, 
          timestamp ASC;
```

Or simply...

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM TableName 
 ORDER BY poster, 
          timestamp;
```

If you don't specify the sort order, SQL automatically assumes ASC or ascending, otherwise, add DESC for descending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp ASC, poster ASC;
```

Please read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).